# Ionic Firestore environment.prod.ts and environment.ts

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

So in google firestore I have two projects:

1. udv-whatever
2. whatever

When building my PWA in the terminal I use:

`ionic build` for udv-whatever and `ionic build --prod` for whatever

But my system doesn't read my environment.prod.ts file, when I use the command `ionic build --prod`

The angular.json file looks like this:

```
"production": {
             
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],

            },
```

What am I missing

I'm expecting that the prod environment file is readed when using `ionic build --prod`